# Can I parameterize a CruiseControl.NET project configuration such that the parameters are exposed by the web interface?

Tags: configuration, cruisecontrol.net, nant, project, parameterized

I am currently trying to use NAnt and CruiseControl.NET to manage various aspects of my software development. Currently, NAnt handles just about everything, including replacing environment specific settings *(e.g., database connection strings)* based on an input target that I specify on the command line.

CruiseControl.NET is used to build the application for the default environment *(dev)* anytime new code is committed. I also want CruiseControl.NET to invoke a build for my additional environments test and stage, but I do not want these to be automatically invoked every time that a dev build invoked (daily) as test and stage deployments happen far less frequently. Test and stage deployments only occur when the application is ready for QA.

I can easily do this by specifying multiple projects, one for each environment. However, I already have many projects configured, one for each milestone in within my application. If I have to setup 3 projects for each milestone the CruiseControl.NET configuration can get out of hand quickly.

**Here is my question:**
Can I parameterize a CruiseControl.NET project configuration such that the parameters are exposed by the web interface?

*Preferably (I think), I could have checkboxes for each environment (e.g., dev, test, stage) exposed in the web interface. A build would be made for each environment that is checked, whether the build was forced or automatic. It would be even better if I could default the checked state.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do anything like that with CruiseControl.NET. It's a good idea, so you might want to submit it as a feature request.

Answer (score 4):

This feature (Dynamic Build Parameters) is currently being worked on for 1.5, and you can try it out in the [nightlies](http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/CCNet-builds/1.5.0/). Here's a [post describing the feature](http://csut017.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/dynamic-build-parameters-some-examples/).

Comment: Thanks! Looks very interesting and I should be able to do what I need. How stable are the nightly builds?

Comment: I haven't tried the recent nightly builds. They seem to be about as stable as the releases...:)

Answer (score 3):

As Scott has mentioned, this isn't available, but it wouldn't take too much just to write a little template and then auto-generate the ccnet.config file given that template and a list of environments in a mail-merge type way.

Comment: I completely agree. This is what we do for now and it works great. As long as you're comfortable with XML, it's fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

This is fully supported now starting with cruisecontrol 1.5: http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parameters