# Using text input parameter on cruisecontrol dashboard

Tags: deployment, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

In my Cruisecontrol task, I wish to xcopy code from a folder name, specified by the user on the dashboard. Is there a way to show a text input box on my CC dashboard along my project, which can be used in the ccnet.config file during xcopy? Or is this too wishful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199819/can-i-parameterize-a-cruisecontrol-net-project-configuration-such-that-the-param

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that CruiseControl.net has now added support for parameters.

A configuration similar to below needs to be added to the  node of your ccnet.config:

```
<parameters>
<selectParameter>
  <name>TargetSite</name>
  <allowedValues>
    <value name="DEV">DEV</value>
    <value name="AT">AT</value>
  </allowedValues>
</selectParameter>
<selectParameter>
  <name>Operation</name>
  <allowedValues>
    <value name="start">start</value>
    <value name="stop">stop</value>
  </allowedValues>
</selectParameter>
</parameters>
```

Doing so would show up these as input parameters when you do a force start!
These parameters, can then be used as variables in the  such as $[TargetSite]